# How can I fix the error preifx 'g' is not recognised as an internal or external command?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, environment-variables, global-variables

I have confirmed node.js and npm are installed as per the screenshot attached. However I also get a message before npm version number as shown and i think its the whole reason why i cant execute some npm commands. I have tried to uninstall nodejs and remove all associated files and re-install it again with no help nor has running command prompt as an admin.

I have also tried solutions that refer to 'npm is not recognized as an internal or external command' and tried to apply with no help. I havent seen a solution that is referring to 'prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command'

All help to understand what the message is all about and how to make sure that it doesnt appear will be appriciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My perseverance paid off.I found the solution here

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8312. I needed to completely remove "ComSpec" variable from my Environment Variable. phew.

[image]